# the imported profile did not contain identities* error while submiting ios application to Apple

Tags: ios, ipad

i am trying to submit an application to the AppStore. At first i prepared the application for upload using iTunesConnect. This step seems to have worked fine. Afterwards i went to xcode and try to submit the application. When i am at the xcode organizer window at archives page , i press distribute , submit to the ios appstore, and then i get the error no identities are available for signing. Then i go to import development profile , i choose my profile which ends to .developmentprofile and then i get the error : The imported profile did not contain identities .Then i go to download entities and i get the error : an administrator must request identities before they are downloaded. I am the administrator . How can i request identities? Is there another way to solve this bug? I would really appreciate it if you would help me with this bug? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: I reset my machine and it worked when I tried again.

Answer (score -1):

follow the instructions in the below page:

[App submission - iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH7-SW1)

Comment: Obviously people have seen this before asking. I have. There is no way to create identities.